# How to avoid using a fall back value for to prop in Link

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a header component that gets data using the context API in react. - It works.

However I don't like the fact that I need to provide a fall back value for the to prop in my link. Just so the page dosn't crash.

My Understanding is that this happens becuase when the page first loads "headerData" is not defind yet. When "headerData" gets the data then the page is rerendered and I get the correct value.

How can I refactor my code so that I don't need to provide a fall back value to my link component?

```
function Header() {
    const headerData = useContext(HeaderContext);

    console.log("heder data");
    console.log(headerData.Menu?.PageUrl);

    return (
        <nav>
            <Link to="/">Logo here</Link>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to={headerData?.Menu?.PageUrl || ""}>Menu</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

From the output in the console I can see that the code runs twice.
[image]

I want to be able to change:

```
<li><Link to={headerData?.Menu?.PageUrl || ""}>Menu</Link></li>
```

to this:

```
<li><Link to={headerData.Menu.PageUrl}>Menu</Link></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally render something else when that data is not available

```
function Header() {
    const headerData = useContext(HeaderContext);

    console.log("heder data");
    console.log(headerData.Menu?.PageUrl);

    return (
        <nav>
            <Link to="/">Logo here</Link>
            <ul>
                {!!headerData?.Menu?.PageUrl
                    ? <li><Link to={headerData?.Menu?.PageUrl!!}>Menu</Link></li>
                    : <></>  // Or whatever you want to have when there is no header data
                    // e.g. <li>Menu</li>
                }
                <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

Comment: This seems very very messy... and is only just doing the same thing as providing a default value. - What I really want to do is make react wait untill useContext has completely loaded before trying to render the JSX

Comment: Your program can get in that state so you *have* to tell it to do something.  You can conditionally not render that whole page on whatever component above using the same technique and put in a spinner or something.  This is a basic part of web development when you have to wait on data.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for the data being arrived, you can wait for it using a url state, and set the state when when the data has arrived. You don't render the link until url is being set:

```
  function Header() {
      const headerData = useContext(HeaderContext);
      const [url, setUrl] = useState();
    
      console.log("heder data");
      console.log(headerData.Menu?.PageUrl);
    
      headerData?.Menu?.PageUrl && !url && setUrl(headerData.Menu.PageUrl);
    
    
      return (
          <nav>
              <Link to="/">Logo here</Link>
              <ul>
                  {url?<li><Link to={url}>Menu</Link></li>:null}
                  <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
      )
    }
```

You could go even further and return nothing as long as url is undefined:

```
  return (<>
    {url?<nav>
          <Link to="/">Logo here</Link>
          <ul>
              <li><Link to={url}>Menu</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>:null}
  </>
  )
}
```

Or use your context directly without a state:

```
  return (<>
    {headerData?.Menu?.PageUrl?<nav>
          <Link to="/">Logo here</Link>
          <ul>
              <li><Link to={headerData.Menu.PageUrl}>Menu</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>:null}
  </>
  )
}
```